# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: socket, .net

We are seeing this exception:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

when submitting REST requests using `System.Net.WebRequest` to a third party API The owner of the API believes the API is OK, and has suggested that there is a transient connectivity problem.

Is that possible with this error, or is this error specific to a failure on the reported host?

We are using the domain name when submitting the requests, and the failure is being reported on an IP belonging to the domain owner

Comment: are you using ssl to encrypt the flow?

Comment: @user1700494 We are using TLS